# IntelliJ: Reference another module from a Maven module not working

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When i create a standard Java module and reference an another module from that (File - Project Structure - Modules - Add ..), i'm able to use the packages from the referenced module.

However, when i reference a module from a **Maven module**, i don't gain access to packages in the referenced module. Is this buggy behavior or am i missing something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working by manually typing out the dependency of the Maven Module to reference eq.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>BusinessLogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>BusinessLogic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with the latest Intellij 12 EAP & have the same issue. To me, this looks like a bug. It should recognize all the dependencies of the other module without having to add each one. 
But if you `Alt + Enter' on the class, it will give you an option to add the module library to your module's dependency. It's better than having to manually add each dependency you need.

Comment: In my environment, alt + enter does add the project to the reference list, but i'm still unable to use the classes in it.

Comment: @JohnNevermore That is strange. I'm able to use the classes in the project, but it could again fail because of other dependencies of the project that are not in your dependency list. Hence, the approach works only for classes that have no other dependency. Are you observing the same or do you get some kind of an error message?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, any fixes?